# Laravel Eloquent getting 2 results in the same query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following inside foreach:

```
$query = SomeFeature::where('feature', $featureName)
                ->orderBy('due_at')
         ;
```

and then after some conditions I am adding or removing from query and at the end I have this:

```
$query->join('user_features', 'users.id', '=', 'user_features.user_id');
$query->join('user_types', 'user_features.type_id', '=', 'user_types.id');
```

which is ok and now I want to get this:

```
->where('group', 'group1')->where('name', 'name1')
->where('group', 'group2')->where('name', 'name2')
```

and then at the end I have:

```
$query->get(['user_features.*', 'users.name', 'user_feature.val']);
```

Basically if I use only one of them like:

```
->where('group', 'group1')->where('name', 'name1')
```

or

```
->where('group', 'group2')->where('name', 'name2')
```

then it works but I want both results to have and to also name them differently in `get()` like `get(['user_feature.val1', 'user_feature.val2'])`

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

EDIT: not full snippet but rather better structured code:

```
 if($featureName == self::FEATURE_DEFAULT) {

   $query->join('user_features', 'users.id', '=', 'user_features.user_id');
   $query->join('user_types', 'user_features.type_id', '=', 'user_types.id')
      ->where('group', 'group1')->where('name', 'name1')
      ->where('group', 'group2')->where('name', 'name2')
   ;
  }
```

Comment: Could you provide a full snippet of the entire query for clarity.

Comment: @HelloSpeakman I added better structured that part

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are trying to do, I believe the issue is because you are doing `WHERE group = 'group1' AND group = 'group2'` which conflicts for obvious reasons.

Try something like this

```
if($featureName == self::FEATURE_DEFAULT) {
   $query->join('user_features', 'users.id', '=', 'user_features.user_id');
   $query->join('user_types', 'user_features.type_id', '=', 'user_types.id')
      ->whereIn('group', ['group1', 'group2'])
      ->whereIn('name', ['name1', 'name2']);
  }
```

This will change your query to `WHERE group IN ('group1', 'group2')` which is not conflicting, alternatively you could try `orWhere()` as well.

**Edit**:
If you're trying to retrieve specific values from another table / record and inject them as columns in your selected row you can try something like this in your query builder, it performs the subquery and grabs the result as "group1" and "group2" columns - adjust it to match your MySQL tables.

```
$query->select(DB::raw("(SELECT group FROM groups WHERE group = 'name1') as group1"));
$query->select(DB::raw("(SELECT group FROM groups WHERE group = 'name2') as group2"));
```

Comment: yes you are right but the problem is that if I use `whereIn` I am not able to say it inside `get` to be like 2 different results... my get looks like: `get(['user_features.val'])` which is basically that field... and I want to be able to have both of these values separated, like `get(['user_features.val1', 'user_features.val2'])`

Comment: Would a subquery work for you? I.e. `SELECT id, name, (SELECT group FROM user_features WHERE group = 'group1') as value1, (SELECT group FROM user_features WHERE group = 'group2') as value2 FROM etc etc ...`

Comment: hmm, I tried before but maybe I did something wrong... Could you add it to your answer?

Comment: I have updated my answer with an example of how to add a select subquery, I think this is what you are trying to do.